# DOM navigation model? (Capybara/Nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, capybara

Before I start re-inventing the wheel, are there any existing gems which support JavaScript-style DOM navigation using Capybara/Nokogiri? I'm thinking of something which parses the whole page into objects to allow this:

```
my_table = page.tables[0]
my_row = my_table.row[3]
my_cell = my_row.cell[2]
my_cell.text.should == "hello world"
```

(I'm looking a Ruby solution rather than a wrapper around some JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you? It is standard Nokogiri

```
my_table = page.css('table')[0] # or page.at_css('table')
my_row = my_table.css('tr')[3] # or my_table.at_xpath('tr[position()=4]')
my_cell = my_row.css('td,th')[2]
my_cell.text.should == "hello world"
```

You could monkeypatch Nokogiri to give it to you exactly, but that doesn't look pretty to me.

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def tables
    css('table')
  end

  def rows
    css('tr')
  end

  def cells
    css('th,td')
  end
end

my_table = page.tables[0]
my_row = my_table.rows[3]
my_cell = my_row.cells[2]
my_cell.text.should == "hello world"
```

Another bad option is the slop decorator, detailed [at the bottom of this page](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet).

Also check out [Testing Views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views) in the Rails guides.

Comment: Yes, that would partly achieve what I need, and is along the lines of what I'm thinking of building, only with a more of an object-based tree, where I can add additional methods specific a particular element types.